# Pivot transactions to metrics

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

There is an easy way to do this I can't remember.  I want to avoid CASE statements or other statements that operate per line.

Transaction Table

[image: client ctype]

What I want it to look like after transformation

[image]

I know I've done this like a million times in the past, but i'm struggling so hard right now.  I know there is an efficient way to go about this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the records in the desired output in that order? And if so, what is the sort logic?

Comment: No, sort order is irrelevant.  Just need to pivot the table that to look like the post transformation example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `pivot` syntax, you can use the `row_number()` window function to force the pivot to maintain the number of records from the sample data. The `order by` specified in the `over` clause is only to satisfy the function requirements.

```
select p.client
, isnull(p.Calls, 0) as Calls
, isnull(p.Orders, 0) as Orders
, isnull(p.OrdRev, 0) as OrdRev
, isnull(p.WebOrde, 0) as WebOrde
from (
    select a.client
    , isnull(a.cType, 'Calls') as cType
    , a.responses
    , row_number() over (order by a.client asc) as row_nbr
    from transaction_table as a
    )  as t
pivot(max(t.responses) for t.cType in ([Calls],[Orders],[OrdRev],[WebOrde])) as p
```